# Реализация "Жизни" Конвея на JavaScript и DOM(Ошибка)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые господа! Написал тут реализацию "Жизни" Конвея кривую под стать своему навыку, выглядит все работающим, но на деле при нажатии на кнопку браузер повисает и больше не оживает. Сколько не смотрел, не нашел почему так происходит. Заранее Вам благодарен за подсказку и совет! Дай Бог Вам здоровья)

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<button id="next">Следующее поколение</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Parameter of the Game
    var height = 9, width = 9;

//Utilities
    function elt(name, type) {
      var elt = document.createElement(name);
      if (type) elt.type = type;
      return elt;
    }  

    function boolFromElt(elt) {
        return elt.checked;
    }

    function gridFromTable(element) {
        var grid =[];
        var children = element.childNodes;
        if(!children)
            return
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
            var row = [];

            for(var j = 0; j < children[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                var bool = boolFromElt(children[i].childNodes[j]);
                row.push(bool);
            }
            grid.push(row);
        }
        return grid;
    }   

//MAIN LOGIC
//Start population
    function startGrid(width, height) {
        if (!grid)
    var grid = elt("table");
        for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            var row = elt("tr");
            for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                var point = elt("input", "checkbox");
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    point.checked = true;
                }
                else
                    point.checked = false;
                row.appendChild(point);
            }
            grid.appendChild(row);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(grid);
    }

//Checking the neighboors
    function countNeighboors(grid, y, x) {
        var count = 0;
        var pointY = y;
        var pointX = x;

        for (y = y - 1; y <= y + 2; y++){
            for (x = x - 1; x <= x + 2; x ++){
                if (y != pointY && x != pointX && y >= 0 && x >= 0 && y <=               grid.length && x <= grid[y].length){
                    counter(y,x);
                }
            }
        } 

        function counter(y, x) {
            if (grid[y][x] == true) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
//Massive of neighbors
    function neighboorsGrid(grid) {
        var total = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i ++) {
            var row = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                row.push(countNeighboors(grid, i, j));
            }
            total.push(row);
        }
        return total;
    }

//Update table
    function updateTable(table, neighboorsGrid) {

        var children = table.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length ; i ++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < children[i].length; j++) {
                if (children[i][j].checked == false) {
                    if (neighboorsGrid[i][j] == 3) {
                        children[i][j].checked = true;
                    }
                }

                else {
                    if (neighboorsGrid[i][j] < 2 || neighboorsGrid[i][j] >     3) {
                        children[i][j].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }


// MAIN TURN FUNCTION

    function turn(table) {
        var grid = gridFromTable(table);
        var neighboors = neighboorsGrid(grid);
        updateTable(table, neighboorsGrid);
    }

// Event Listener
    startGrid(width, height);

    document.querySelector("#next").addEventListener("click", function() {
        turn(document.querySelector("table"));
    })

    </script>
```

Comment: А отладчик-то что говорит? Ну и попутно, если `neighboorsGrid` — это функция, то почему Вы пытаетесь обратиться к ней, как к массиву?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам еще нужен ответ:

Проблема заключается в функции countNeighboors,а конкретно в циклах for.

Например в первом из них вы используете такое условие:(y <= y + 2), но оно по определению всегда true и программа никак не может выйти из цикла.

То есть вам надо заменить названия счетчиков, чтобы они не совпадали с другими именами и не модифицировались нечаянно.